# importing files to test functions in clojure

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

i have a main src folder which has another folder say xyz which has a main.clj file , i have another folder test which has folder xyz and file main_test.clj , but when i run : lein test it says :

lein test user
Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

i need to test functions of main.clj , i am very new to clojure any help would be great.

```
    --- project1
       |____src
       |     |_____main.clj
       |_____test
       |     |_____main_test.clj 
       |_____project.clj
```

i have tried different ways with require and load . i have to write the unit tests .

Answer (score 4):

If your source file is `src/xyz/main.clj` and its `ns` form calls it `xyz.main`, then make sure you have `test/xyz/main_test.clj` and its `ns` form calls it `xyz.main-test` -- note the hyphen there corresponding to the `_` in the filename.

If that intermediate folder is `x_y_z` then the corresponding namespace segment would be `x-y-z`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the test directory to the classpath for running tests.  This is for Leiningen done in `project.clj`:

```
(defproject project1
  …
  :test-paths ["test"]
  …)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sean has some good points.  If that doesn't work, try the following to get a baseline setup that runs:

```
~/expr > lein new app sample
~/expr > cd sample
~/expr/sample > lein test

lein test sample.core-test

lein test :only sample.core-test/a-test

FAIL in (a-test) (core_test.clj:7)
FIXME, I fail.
expected: (= 0 1)
  actual: (not (= 0 1))

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
1 failures, 0 errors.
Tests failed.
```